# Error asociacion sequelize Error: modelTable.hasMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model

Tags: javascript, orm, sequelize.js, sequelize

Tengo un problema donde al realizar una consulta entre la tabla campaña y proyectos me presenta el siguiente error **campaigns.hasMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model**

**Consulta**

```
   const [error, campaigns] = await catchify(
        campaignsModel.findAll({
            include : [ { // incluye a los clientes
            model: clientModel,
            as: 'client',
          } ] ,
          include : [ { 
            model: projectModel,
            as: 'projects',
          } ] ,
            order: [
            ['created_at', 'DESC'],
        ],limit: limit,
        offset: offset,})


    );
```

**ERROR**

> Error: campaigns.hasMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model at Function.hasMany
>   (/home/jose/be-there-api/node_modules/sequelize/lib/associations/mixin.js:13:13)
>   at Object.
>   (/home/jose/be-there-api/models/schemas/gett/campaigns.js:70:16)

**Modelo campaña**

```
    'use strict';
// VENDOR
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
import ClientModel from './clients';
import ProjectsModel from './projects';
// LIBS & CONSTANTS
import { database } from '../../../config/services';


const modelDefinition = {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        field: 'id',
    },
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT,
        allowNull: false,
        field: 'name',
    },
    clientId: {
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        allowNull: false,
        field: 'client_id',
    },
    startDate: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
        field: 'start_date',
    },
    endDate: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
        field: 'end_date',
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
        field: 'created_at',
        defaultValue: Sequelize.DataTypes.NOW,
    },
    updatedAt: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: true,
        field: 'updated_at'
    },
    deletedAt: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: true,
        field: 'deleted_at'
    }

};


const modelOptions = {
    getterMethods: {
    },

    setterMethods: {
    },

    schema: 'gett'
};

const campaignsModel = database.define('campaigns', modelDefinition, modelOptions);
```

campaignsModel.hasMany(ProjectsModel, {
    as: 'projects',
    foreignKey: 'campaignId',
    sourceKey: 'id',
});

```
campaignsModel.belongsTo(ClientModel, {
    foreignKey: 'clientId',
    targetKey: 'id',
});




export default campaignsModel;
```

**Modelo proyectos**

```
'use strict';
// VENDOR
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
import uuid from 'uuid/v4';
// LIBS & CONSTANTS
import { database } from '../../../config/services';
import ClientModel from './clients';
import GuidelineModel from './guidelines';
import CampaignsModel from './campaigns';
// MODELS
import MovesModel from './moves';

// 1: The model schema.

const modelDefinition = {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        defaultValue: uuid(),
        field: 'id',
    },
    code: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        field: 'code',
    },
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        field: 'name',
    },
    clientId: {
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        allowNull: false,
        field: 'client_id',
    },
    questionnaireId: {
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        allowNull: false,
        field: 'questionnaire_id',
    },
    campaignId: {
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        allowNull: false,
        field: 'campaign_id',
    },
    guidelineId: {
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        allowNull: false,
        field: 'guideline_id',
    },
    moveId: {
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        allowNull: false,
        field: 'move_id',
    },
    status: {
        //TODO definir estados
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        field: 'status',
    },
    visitsPerLocation: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: true,
        field: 'visits_per_location',
    },
    usersCharacteristics: {
        type: Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.INTEGER),
        field: 'users_characteristics',
    },
    clientsCharacteristics: {
        type: Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.INTEGER),
        field: 'clients_characteristics',
    },
    locationsCharacteristics: {
        type: Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.INTEGER),
        field: 'locations_characteristics',
    },
    startDate: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
        field: 'start_date',
    },
    endDate: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
        field: 'end_date',
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
        field: 'created_at',
        defaultValue: Sequelize.DataTypes.NOW,
    },
    updatedAt: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: true,
        field: 'updated_at',
    },
    deletedAt: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: true,
        field: 'deleted_at',
    },
};

const modelOptions = {
    getterMethods: {},

    setterMethods: {},

    schema: 'gett',
};

const ProjectsModel = database.define(
    'projects',
    modelDefinition,
    modelOptions
);


ProjectsModel.belongsTo(CampaignsModel,{
    foreignKey: 'campaignId',
    targetKey: 'id',
});

ProjectsModel.belongsTo(MovesModel, {
    foreignKey: 'moveId',
    targetKey: 'id',
});

ProjectsModel.belongsTo(ClientModel, {
    as: 'clients',
    foreignKey: 'clientId',
    targetKey: 'id',
});

ProjectsModel.belongsTo(GuidelineModel, {
    foreignKey: 'guidelineId',
    targetKey: 'id',
});

export default ProjectsModel;
```

Answer (score -1):

Tienes que tener en mente que por lo general sequelize crea las relaciones entre las tablas basándose en el orden en que estas son creadas con `sequelize.define()`. Pienso que puedes tener problemas  al primero crear el `campaignsModel.hasMany()` y luego en el `ProjectsModel.belongsTo(campaignsModel)`. Pienso que debes usar una de las dos, pero no ambas (puedo estar equivocado en esto, pero lo que tienes es que ver como quedan las tablas definidas en tu DBMS luego de que las mismas se crean. Recuerda también que debes crear el modelo de proyectos primero que el de campañas. El orden en que los estás creando no queda obvio por como compartiste el código.

Un detalle que pienso que está mal, es el siguiente:

```
campaignsModel.hasMany(ProjectsModel, {
   as: 'campaigns',
   foreignKey: 'campaignId',
   sourceKey: 'id',
});
```

Si una campaña tiene muchos proyectos, ¿no debería de llamarse "projects" en el "as:"?

Espero te sea de ayuda mi respuesta y éxito en tu proyecto.